# Objective C synthesized property add vs set?

Tags: objective-c, properties

So I know of course about the basic property getters and setters.

```
- (void)setAnObject:(NSObject *)anObject
{

}

- (NSObject *)anObject
{
    return _anObject;
}
```

But I noticed in code completion today that for every property these add methods are created as well. I did some searching and couldn't find reference of them. What are these and what do they do?

```
- (void)addAnObject:(NSSet *)objects
{

}

- (void)addAnObjectObject:(<#object-type#> *)object
{

}
```

Comment: Would these be core data objects by any chance?

Comment: No they aren't. In one case they were but I made a blank project and just created an `NSObject *anObject` property and nothing else just to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are [KVC-compliant accessors](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172-BAJEAIEE) for the `anObject` property, which Xcode probably thinks is a collection type (e.g. NSSet). (**Edit:** Xcode may not think that, but is suggesting the completions anyway.)

Comment: Awesome thanks. They aren't collection type specific as anything that is a descendant of NSObject has them but this is exactly the documentation i was looking for.

Comment: If the property definitely isn't a collection type, you might consider filing a bug against this completion - it doesn't really make sense to `addAnObjectObject` if `anObject` can't contain other objects.

Comment: Hmm I suppose not. I'll do a little more research and go from there. Thanks for the perfect info. :)

Comment: My pleasure! For future reference: I just filed rdar://12151538 against this behavior.